# Using NUFFT in Matlab R2015a

Tags: matlab, nfft

###### MatlabR2015a in Windows10 (X32).

Because in 2015 version, there is not NUFFT, i downloaded, code for NUFFT from mathworks site (code by Matthew Ferrara).

After i made "mex FGG_Convolution1D.c", (as described in "Overview"), i received :

mex FGG_Convolution1D_type2.c

Building with 'lcc-win32'.

MEX completed successfully.

The same for

mex FGG_Convolution2D.c

mex FGG_Convolution2D_type2.c

mex FGG_Convolution3D.c

mex FGG_Convolution3D_type2.c

Well, after that, i create a sin function (x) over non uniform time intervals, but when i made :
X=nufft(x)
i received this error message :

> > X=nufft(x);
> > Undefined function or variable 'nufft'

Also i tried : 
X=FGG_Convolution1D.c (x), and received the same error :

Undefined function or variable 'FGG_Convolution1D.c'

Anybody can help ?

Comment: Take a closer look at the examples to see how to use the functions. The FEX submission you refer to will not create `nufft`, but various other compiled functions that you can use with the appropriate Matlab 'wrapper'. So for 1D, look at `fgg_1D_experiment`. From what I can see you need to call the `FGG_1d_type1` Matlab function, which will call the appropriate C-Mex program.

Comment: Rinkert, thanks to your advises i looked in fgg_1D_experiment, and then i call the FGG_1d_type1. I see that FGG_1d_type1, asks for "f", "knots", "N", "accuracy", "GridListx". In my experiment i had 32 samples of a sin function over 32 non uniform time intervals. So (if i understood well), in place of "f", i put the 32 samples of my sin function, in place of "knots", i put the 32 non uniform positions of time intervals, in place of "N" i put number 32, and nothing in place of GridListx (i completely cannot imagine what is this, as probably the rest { "f", "knots", "N", "accurancy"}).

Comment: This, produced a column of 32 complex numbers, as i expected. Now, in the FFT case, i know how to "extract" the basic frequency-ies, from these results (the 32  complex numbers in this case), as i plot the "abs" of it against 32 bins were each bin's label is the (fsampling/Number) of samples. But in case of NUFFT, against what to plot ? I know that this is not a case of not understand to write a code, but to understand terminology related to the NUFFT, but i am new into this and if somebody can explain, it will be a great help for me.